# Yii 2 Oracle DB ERROR! working on xampp Windows / not working on CentOs Apache2 oracle db

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, yii2, oracle-call-interface

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1405 OCIStmtFetch: ORA-01405: column value is NULL
>   (/opt/oci/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:446)
>   The SQL being executed was: WITH USER_SQL AS (SELECT * FROM "devices"),
>   PAGINATION AS (SELECT USER_SQL.*, rownum as rowNumId FROM USER_SQL)
>   SELECT *
>   FROM PAGINATION
>   WHERE rownum <= 20
>   Error Info: Array
>   (
>       [0] => HY000
>       [1] => 1405
>       [2] => OCIStmtFetch: ORA-01405: column value is NULL
>    (/opt/oci/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:446)
>   )
>   ↵
>   Caused by: PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1405 OCIStmtFetch: ORA-01405: pobraną wartością kolumny jest NULL
>   (/opt/oci/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:446)
>
> in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 829

When I put this select into sql browser it works perfectly on xampp oracle db & Windows, but not on production CentOS 6.1 and apache2 oracle db 11
Please Help

Comment: [SOLVED] in fields of type LOB ex. CLOB don`t use NULL`s use empty strings

Answer (score 0):

Try using nvl function in oracle. For model that contain clob column. Using sql data provider instead.

For example. Using data provider in yii2 in controller action index

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POST
')->queryScalar();

        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => "SELECT ID, NVL(TEXT_WITH_CLOB, 'None')  FROM POST",
            'key' => 'ID',
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'ID',
                    'TEXT_WITH_CLOB',
                ],
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```